# Error creating new .NET core project in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I downloaded and installed Visual Studio Update 3 and .NET Core 1.0
   for Visual Studio.

I restarted my machine as instructed by the
   prompts.

Anytime I try to create any of the .NET core projects from
   VS I get the error dialog:

> The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070002)

Here is the last few nodes from my `ActivityLog`:

```
<entry>
    <record>736</record>
    <time>2016/07/02 21:54:33.961</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
    <guid>{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>737</record>
    <time>2016/07/02 21:54:33.961</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.SolutionNavigatorPackage]</description>
    <guid>{CF6A5C16-83B0-4D04-B702-195C35C6E887}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>738</record>
    <time>2016/07/02 21:54:34.023</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>739</record>
    <time>2016/07/02 21:54:34.023</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
    <guid>{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>740</record>
    <time>2016/07/02 21:54:34.148</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{5F2E5E42-4192-4D79-A0D8-1D881E808829}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>741</record>
    <time>2016/07/02 21:54:34.148</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [ProviderPackage]</description>
    <guid>{5F2E5E42-4192-4D79-A0D8-1D881E808829}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>742</record>
    <time>2016/07/02 21:54:34.258</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [ProviderPackage]</description>
    <guid>{5F2E5E42-4192-4D79-A0D8-1D881E808829}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>743</record>
    <time>2016/07/02 21:54:34.620</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>SccDisplayInformation.SolutionOptions</source>
    <description>Unable to load solution user option &apos;SccProvider.Solution.LoadCount&apos;</description>
  </entry>
```